# Python pip, virtualenv, virtualwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Is there an easy way to install all three of these things? It seems like there are a lot of confusing steps to get these to work. What's the most efficient way to get all 3 to work and perhaps even django.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Run those commands (possibly as root):

```
$ easy_install pip
$ pip install virtualenv
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then, to install django in a virtual environment:

```
$ mkvirtualenv myenv
$ pip install django
```

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu, it's also possible to get pip first through `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. That might be slightly more stable with your package versions. You can also `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` but I use `pip` myself after getting `python-pip`.